# Change react hook state from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook component like this:

```js
import React, { useState} from "react";

const MyComponent = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const cleanValue = () => {
    setValue(0);
  };

  return (<span><button onClick={()=>setValue(1)}/>{value}<span>)
}
```

I want to reset value from the parent component. How I can call clean value from parent component? the parent component is a stateful component.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the parent has to control the child state then probably the state must reside in the parent component itself. However you can still update child state from parent using ref and exposing a reset method in child. You can make use of `useImperativeHandle` hook to allow the child to only expose specific properties to the parent

```js
const { useState, forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle} = React;


const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return (
     <div>
      <MyComponent ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => {ref.current.cleanValue()}} type="button">Reset</button>
     </div>
  )
}

const MyComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  
   const cleanValue = () => {
    setValue(0);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
     return {
      cleanValue: cleanValue
     }
  });

  return (<span><button type="button" onClick={()=>setValue(1)}>Increment</button>{value}</span>)
});
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: IMHO this looks like a Hook workaround for a derived state situation and [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), so I posted my answer using 1 of the recommendations... but `useImperativeHandle` could be useful in more complicated situations, when the state store would have to live outside of React in some imperative library

Comment: For TypeScript users wanting to use this answer's approach, here is a way to have the type-data for an imperative-handle inferred: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/7cff24b17867da305fff12c6f8ef6f96

Answer (score 12):

From the React documentation about [Fully uncontrolled component with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key):

> In order to reset the value ..., we can use the special React attribute called `key`. When a `key` changes, *React will create a new component instance rather than update the current one*. Keys are usually used for dynamic lists but are also useful here.

In this case, we can use a simple counter to indicate the need for a new instance of `MyComponent` after pressing the `Reset` button:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Parent = () => {
  const [instanceKey, setInstanceKey] = useState(0)
  const handleReset = () => setInstanceKey(i => i + 1)
  return (
   <div>
    <MyComponent key={instanceKey} />
    <button onClick={handleReset} type="button">Reset</button>
   </div>
  )
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  return (
    <span>
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>setValue(v => v + 1)}>{value}</button>
    </span>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't / shouldn't. Using hooks instead of stateful class components doesn't change the fact that if you want the parent to own the state, you need to declare the state in the parent.

It should look something like this, depending on when you want to reset the value (here I used another button):

```
const MyButton = (props) = (
  // Whatever your button does, e.g. styling
  <span>
    <button {...props} />
  <span>
)


const Parent = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const cleanValue = () => setValue(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton onClick={() => setValue(1)}>
        {value}
      </MyButton>
      <button onClick={cleanValue}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So, how to reset the value? I just want to reset it.

Comment: when possible, this would be the preferable solution, a.k.a. [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - but it *is* actually possible to create a new instance of a child Component (which is equivalent to resetting - see my answer)