# Changing the child's useState from Parent component react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have e child component named Window and I have this useState in Window component:

```
Window Component:
      const [showWindow, setShowWindow] = useState(false);
```

Imagine this is the parent component

```
Parent component :
/////
////
////
<Window/>
<Button/ onClick={()=>{
setShowWindow(true)
}}>
/////
/////
```

As it can be seen I have a Button component here and I want to set the showWindow to 'true' through it.

How can I change the useState in the child component from its parent component like this example? How can I access to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to share states between components using the useState() hook in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451584/is-it-possible-to-share-states-between-components-using-the-usestate-hook-in-r)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change react hook state from parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889357/change-react-hook-state-from-parent-component)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to have the parent, able to change state that is defined in the child.

I don't believe this is possible exactly as described. A better solution might be to define the state inside the parent, then pass down the state to the child.

```
Parent component :
 const [showWindow, setShowWindow] = useState(false);

<Window showWindow = {showWindow} setShowWindow = {setShowWindow}/>
<Button/ onClick={()=>{
setShowWindow(true)
}}>
```

that should produce the functionality I think you are after. Furthermore, you can also pass the setter if you need to change the window within the window component ( which you likely do if this is a popup type component)

As another answer suggested, a further solution would be to use global state/context. This would allow you to avoid passing state around, but has more overhead

Answer (score 3):

To invoke functions in a child component use the [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook in the `Window` component and [forward a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) from the parent component to the child to imperatively invoke a function to update the state in the child.

Example:

Window

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useState } from 'react';

const Window = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [showWindow, setShowWindow] = useState(false);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showWindow: () => setShowWindow(true),
  }));

  ...

});
```

Parent

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

...

const windowRef = useRef();

...

<Window ref={windowRef} />
<Button onClick={() => windowRef.current.showWindow()}>
  Show Window
</Button>
```

[image: Edit changing-the-childs-usestate-from-parent-component-react-hooks]

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to reload the child component, causing it to reset the useState to its initial state.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ParentComponent() {
  const [resetKey, setResetKey] = useState(0);

  const resetChildComponent = () => {
    // Increment a key to reset the child component
    setResetKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={resetChildComponent}>Reset Child</button>
      <ChildComponent key={resetKey} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponent() {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState('Initial State');

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Child State: {childState}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setChildState('New State')}>Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).